# Debugging string is empty from one function yet populated in another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

I've either been starting at things for too long (highly likely) or something weird is going on with a particular property. When I debug the property `_animalType` from my PlayerController script `Debug.Log("Animal Type is : " + _animalType);` it's coming back as an empty string, yet when I debug it from CanvasController `Debug.Log(player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalType);` it shows that the string is populated with the correct data. Can anyone see what might be happening here? Thank you!

'CanvasController.cs'

```
    public void PrepareAnimalData()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoPrepareAnimalData());
        Debug.Log("Send To Forest Button Pressed.");
    }

    IEnumerator DoPrepareAnimalData()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        RenderTexture tmp = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = BackLayerController.RenderTexture;

        TmpTexture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, RenderTextureSize.x, RenderTextureSize.y), 0, 0, false);

        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        PlayerController.animalTex = TmpTexture2D; // set PlayerController animalTex to TmpTexture2D 
        player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().TexToBytes(); // run function from PlayerController
        player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalType = PageConfig.UniqueId; // set animalType in PlayerController

        Debug.Log(PageConfig.UniqueId);
        Debug.Log(player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalType);
    }}
```

PlayerController.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public static Texture2D animalTex;
    private byte[] textureBytes;

    private string _animalType;
    public string AnimalType
    {
        get
        {
            return _animalType;
        }
        set
        {
            _animalType = value;
        }
    }
    private string _playerID;
    public string PlayerID
    {
        get
        {
            return _playerID;
        }
        set
        {
            _playerID = value;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        GameObject gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
            return;
    }

    public void TexToBytes()
    {
        textureBytes = animalTex.GetRawTextureData();
        DebugAnimalData();
    }

    public void DebugAnimalData()
    {
        Debug.Log("Byte Array Length is : " + textureBytes.Length);
        Debug.Log("Animal Type is : " + _animalType);
        Debug.Log("Player ID is : " + _playerID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn about [auto properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)..

Comment: i do know about auto properties. when i'm done debugging these properties they will be configured for set only

Comment: What's the point in having a property that you can't read?

Comment: Fair enough, but changing these properties to auto properties isn't going to solve the actually problem though, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called this (which shows it outputs the info)

`player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().TexToBytes();`

before you set it

```
player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalType = PageConfig.UniqueId; // set animalType in PlayerController
```

Answer (score 1):

When `TexToBytes` is called, it internally invokes `DebugAnimalData` logging data. At this time, `_animalType` is still initialized to `null`. However, after this, your next statement is setting `_animalType` through Setter and thus, next Debug logs start logging the value